# display custom angular script template as table detail row

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi i am quite new to angular programming and I had a question on hwo to include angular script templates into a table

Basically I have a base directive table that displays data, but I want anyone who uses that base directive to provide a template of how they want the detail row to look like. I thought the best way to do this was from an "angular script template"

This fiddle describes what I want to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/g0b1xk9s/1/

Basically in the fiddle I was wondering if it was possible to display the template with id (template1) where I have the code

```
      <div ng-include src="template1">

      </div>
```

Is this possible or should I find another way to do this?

Thank you for the help

Comment: Where exactly the template fits in your fiddle? I did not understand where do you intend to use the template

Comment: sorry i attached the wrong fiddle...updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can and [script tags are documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) as a valid template approach

```
 <div ng-include src="'template'"></div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template">
    <table border="1">
      <tr ng-repeat="note in ctrl.notes">
        <td>{{note.label}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat-end>
        <td>Done: {{note.done}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </script>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/vZ80FUljS5MnLsMNb8Ol?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for this!! was missing the ''... haha